# changing the colour of a UIButton

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I have a button which is entirely black and white. I would like the white parts to flash with green colour when the user presses the button. I guess I could do it with another button set over the base button and than animate the alpha value but that feels rather cumbersome.  Can you set me on a right track regarding this issue?

Comment: Check out this demo : http://www.code4app.net/ios/This-is-a-custom-button-with-flash-like-effect./54b39995e247410e383a9685